# ¿Cómo mantener el inicio de sesión y entrar directamente al main Activity cuando el usuario ya inició sesión con google?

Tags: java, android, login, autenticación

Tengo una aplicación donde implementé inicio de sesión con *Google*, pero no sé cómo hacer para que al cerrar la aplicación y volver a entrar, no se deba aplastar de nuevo el botón de inicio de sesión. Actualmente no hay necesidad de volver a poner usuario y contraseña, pero igual se debe aplastar el botón, y este entra al main activity; estuve investigando y dicen algo de persistencia, pero creo que sí se mantiene activa la sesión, solo no sé cómo indicarle a la activity de inicio de sesión que si ya se ha ingresado antes, vaya directamente al main.

Este es mi código de inicio de sesión:

```
 public class LoginFireBase extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Varibales públicas
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    static final int GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 123;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ImageButton imgIniciar;
    ImageView imgHolcim,imgLogo;
    TextView txtIncio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_fire_base);
        mAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
        if(msg != null){
            if(msg.equals("cerrarSesion")){
                cerrarSesion();
            }
        }

        imgHolcim=findViewById(R.id.imgHolcim);
        imgIniciar=findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        imgLogo=findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
        txtIncio=findViewById(R.id.txtIniciarSesion);
        Animation animationarriba= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.desplaza_arriba);
        Animation animationAbajo= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.desplaza_abajo);
        imgHolcim.setAnimation(animationarriba);
        imgLogo.setAnimation(animationarriba);
        imgIniciar.setAnimation(animationAbajo);
        txtIncio.setAnimation(animationAbajo);
    }
    private void cerrarSesion() {
        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                task -> updateUI(null));
    }
    public void iniciarSesion(View view) {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent( data);
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                if (account != null) firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.w("TAG", "Fallo el inicio de sesión con google.", e);
            }
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("TAG", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("error");
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }
    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (user != null) {
            HashMap<String, String> info_user = new HashMap<String, String>();
            info_user.put("user_name", user.getDisplayName());
            info_user.put("user_email", user.getEmail());
            info_user.put("user_photo", String.valueOf(user.getPhotoUrl()));
            info_user.put("user_id", user.getUid());
            finish();
        } else {
            System.out.println("sin registrarse");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Para mantener la sesión iniciada utiliza los sharedPreference en el cual guardas la contraseña hasheada o un token pero nunca la contraseña en texto plano y si existe redireccionar a la pantalla del usuario

Comment: @christian Si guardas mi contraseña, hasheada o no, tenemos un problema. Las contraseñas ***NUNCA*** se guardan al alcance de los usuarios. ***JAMÁS***. En cuanto al login, en el `onStart` coges la cuenta pero no haces nada con ella... Si ese método que llamas ahí devuelve algo diferente a `null`, es que el usuario está logueado. Compruébalo y lanza la siguiente *Activity*, y ya está :)

Comment: Si funciono solo aumente la condicional en el onStart! Gracias por la ayuda :3
protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (account != null)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

Comment: Te recomendaría que llames `finish();` después de `startActivity(intent);`. Esto para que cuando navegues hacia atrás no veas la actividad de Login.

Comment: amm ya ok muchas gracias @favs, si tengo algunos problemas con eso de navegar hacia atrás, estoy usando una activity drawer navigation como main y dentro de los fragments principales tengo tabs entonces si estoy en un tab de otro fragment y voy hacia atrás no se me carga el contenido de ese tab solo se ve las pestañas.

Comment: Vale. No podría decirte el problema en sí sin ver el código, pero pueda que tengas un problema con tu Fragment Back Stack por el uso de `add`, `replace`, etc.